Checking with powershell that an application is running
I am trying to create a script with powershell, that a game is running and send the information to "Uptime Kuma" via push.
But, something is wrong in the code, that although it is not open it is sending the notification.
$satisfactory = Get-Process UnrealServer-Win64-Shipping
$url = "http://:3001/api/push/3xlVsB4AVr?status=up&msg=OK&ping="
while ($true) {
# Check if the service is running
if (!$satisfactory.started) {
# Send a push notification
$pingTime = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($url + $pingTime)
}
# Wait for XX seconds before checking again
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}


try to use get-process inside of the loop.

Powershell AFAIK does not have a ToString method. Check out the docs here on Get-Date https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.4. Try the below and see if that works for you:
# Define the name of the process to check
$processName = "UnrealServer-Win64-Shipping"

# Define the API endpoint URL
$url = "http://localhost:3001/api/push/3xlVsB4AVr"

# Continuously check if the process is running and send a push notification if it is, otherwise log to the console
while ($true) {
    # Check if the process is running
    $process = Get-Process -Name $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    if ($process) {
        # Send a push notification if the process is running
        $pingTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
        $pingUrl = $url + "?status=up&msg=OK&ping=" + $pingTime
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $pingUrl -Method Post
    } else {
        # Log to the console if the process is not running
        Write-Host "The process $processName is not running."
    }

    # Wait for a few seconds before checking again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}


I deleted the "--Method Post" from the line "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $pingUrl -Method Post" and it works perfectly. Thank you.

No problem, yea I wasnt sure if it was a GET or POST. Glad to hear it works.

Get-Date by default returns a [DateTime] object, and THAT has a .ToString() method. By encapsulating Get-Date in round parenthesis it is treated as its output. (Get-Date).ToString() is basically a shorthand for $TempVar=Get-Date; $TempVar.ToString(); Remove-Variable TempVar
